# How to iterate over html elements with same attribute using jquery and look for onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to loop over each element with same attribute and make a ajax call whenever there is a onclick event in any of the elements.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($("#workon"),function(){
       $(this).find("#wanalearn_request").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var this_ = this;
          # ajaxPost is just a custom ajax post function 
          ajaxPost($(this).attr('href'),{},function(content) {
             $(this_).find('span').text(content.wanalearns_count);
          });
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Dom elements should have unique ids. That means ```$.each($("#workon")``` is conceptually wrong. You should use classes or custom data attributes to mark them.

Answer (score 0):

Try use 'on' instead:

```
$('#workon').on('click', '#wanalearn_request', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var link = $(e.target).closest('a');

  $.post(link.attr('href'), '' /* the payload must be a serialized query string in this case */, function (content) {

    link.find('span').text(content.wanalearns_count);

  });

});
```

Comment: Using the above code it grabs only the first element of the series of element with same attribute.